# Как перенести комментарии из друпал 7 в систему  disqus?

Tags: drupal, disqus

Добрый день. Подскажите как перенести комментарии из друпал 7 в систему  disqus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я писал в своем блоге инструкцию по переносу  [миграция комментариев из Drupal 7 в Disqus](http://drup.by/articles/migraciya-kommentariev-iz-drupal-7-v-disqus)